# why does this bootloader only prints 'S'

Tags: c, gcc, x86, bootloader

I am writing a simple x86 bootloader.

this is the c program that im having trouble with: `test4.c`

```
__asm__(".code16\n");
__asm__("jmpl $0x0, $main\n");

void prints ( char* str )
{
    char* pStr = str;

    while( *pStr )
    {
        __asm__ __volatile (
            "int $0x10"
            :
            : "a"(0x0e00 | *pStr), "b"(7)
        );
        pStr++;
    }
}

void main ( ) 
{
    char*  str = "\n\rHello World\n\r";
    char* pStr = str;

    while( *pStr )
    {
        __asm__ __volatile (
            "int $0x10"
            :
            : "a"(0x0e00 | *pStr)
        );
        pStr++;
    }
    prints ( str );

}
```

when i try to print a string within main function, it works. But when i pass the string to another function which does carry out same instructions but still prints only `S` to the screen. So the final output looks something like this:

```
Hello World
S
```

Here is the linker file i used: `test.ld`

```
ENTRY(main);
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x7C00;
    .text : AT(0x7C00)
    {
        *(.text);
    }
    .sig : AT(0x7DFE)
    {
        SHORT(0xaa55);
    }
}
```

Here are the commands i used to compile the c program and to link it

```
$ gcc -c -g -Os -m32 -march=i686 -ffreestanding -Wall -Werror test4.c -o test4.o
$ ld -melf_i386 -static -Ttest.ld -nostdlib --nmagic -o test4.elf test4.o
$ objcopy -O binary test4.elf test4.bin
```

and i used `bochs` emulator to test out this bootloader

Comment: A standalone program has to set up the stack and segment registers.

Comment: See duskwuffs comment on not using GCC's 16-bit code. Openwatcom is the best choice for a _C_ compiler targeting 16-bit code IMHO. However, if you know what you are doing, understand the nuances about the generated code by GCC (and its limitations) you could look at something like this [code example](http://www.capp-sysware.com/misc/ircasm/gccboot/) . This is pretty much designed to print using BIOS interrupts from a bootloader.

Comment: Pretty much an exact duplicate of [Help in building an 16 bit os](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713340/help-in-building-an-16-bit-os)

Comment: Anyway, in your situation the problem is on this line `__asm__(".code16\n");` . It should be `__asm__(".code16gcc\n");` . Using `.code16` will mess up the stack as it will assume 16-bit CALLs (instead of the 32-bit *CALL* that GCC really expects). This will cause argument to appear in the wrong location on the stack. I was going to write an answer but found this question is pretty much a duplicate of this [Stackoverflow question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713340/help-in-building-an-16-bit-os)

Comment: At the bottom of `main` there is no place to return to. So you should consider putting an infinite loop at the bottom of `main` with something like `while(1);` or use `__asm__ ("cli; hlt;");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with GCC. Ignore all the tutorials that say that you can -- they are wrong.

What's most important to keep in mind is that *GCC is not a 16-bit compiler*. The `__asm__(".code16\n")` directive does not turn it into one; it merely confuses the assembler into retargeting GCC's output from 32-bit x86 to 16-bit. This will cause strange and unexpected behavior, especially in any code using pointers.

If you want to write an x86 bootloader, you will need to:

- Use a C compiler that can specifically target 16-bit x86 ("real mode"). Consider the OpenWatcom toolchain, for instance.
- Become *very* familiar with the quirks of x86 real mode -- particularly segmentation.
- Write some portions of the bootloader in assembly, particularly the startup code.

Comment: I'd also recommend that if you are using OpenWatcom targeting 16-bit code and you are considering doing this from a bootloader - [JLOC](http://geezer.osdevbrasil.net/johnfine/jloc.htm) linker is a godsend. Unfortunately it is a DOS program with no source code but will run well with emulators like DOSEMU on Linux.

Comment: I do not recommend using GCC for 16-bit code for reasons you gave. However it is in fact doable but only if you have a excellent understanding of what goes on under the hood. You'll have all ends of problems with pointers but they can be minimized if the entire program can be loaded into memory in the first 64k of memory and if CS=DS=ES=SS=0 . Of course none of the code generate by GCC's `.code16` directive will run on anything earlier than a 386 processor (8086/80186/80286 and variants).